# Gallery with jQuery 1.6.4

Tags: javascript

How do I implement a gallery like [the following one](http://tympanus.net/Development/WaveDisplayEffect/index4.html) with jQuery 1.6.4 and Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it - for instance, it depends on where the images are coming from. You could do it with Views for instance, creating a list of images, adding the correct classes, and applying the js from your custom theme.

Comment: I created view with all necessary fields and field classes. I applied all js files needed, but the slideshow did not work. Only difference was version of jQuery. By default Drupal has v.1.4.4. I installed module jQuery update, and got v.1.5.2. Slideshow does not work.

Comment: If you really need jQuery 1.6.4, you can use multiple jQuery versions simultaneously. See http://drupal.org/node/1309382#comment-5115386 for some helpful code and explanation.